# jQuery, click event, too much recursion

Tags: jquery, click

Could somebody tell me why this code:

```
$('#places-view > tbody').find('td').click(function(evt) {
    var td = $(this),
        input = td.find('input');
        console.log('click');
        console.log(input.attr('disabled'), 'disabled');
        if (! input.attr('disabled')) {
            input.trigger('click');
            console.log('inner click');
        }
})
```

throwing too much recursion error...

Regards

Answer (score 6):

To prevent event bubbling, place `event.stopPropagation()` in the handler for your `input` element's click event.

```
$('#places-view input').click(function(event) {

      // This will prevent the click event from bubbling up and firing
      //    the click event on your <td>
    event.stopPropagation();

      // run the rest of your click code
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

---

**EDIT:** As **@Pointy** noted, it may be your intention to have the same handler handle both events, or at least have the `td` handler still fire when you click the `input`.

If that's the case, you'll just need to check to see if the `td` handler was fired by a click on the `input`, and if so, prevent the `input.trigger("click")` from running:

```
$('#places-view > tbody').find('td').click(function(evt) {
    var td = $(this),
        input = td.find('input');
        console.log('click');
        console.log(input.attr('disabled'), 'disabled');
        if (! input.attr('disabled')) {
                // If the target of the click was not the input,
                //   then trigger the click on the input
            if( input.not( evt.target ).length ) {
                input.trigger('click');
                console.log('inner click');
            }
        }
});
```

Another way to do the test would be:

```
if(input[0] != evt.target) {...
```

Both of these approaches assume that there's just one `input`. If that's not the case, then you'll need to give the input an identifier to allow the test to be more specific.

Comment: This is true, but I have to wonder whether that'd be a good idea. If he indeed wants to handle "click" at the `<td>` level, it may be bad to cancel bubbling at the `<input>` because that'll shunt off the clicks to the `<td>`. Of course it depends on what else is in the table cell.

Comment: @Pointy - You're right. My assumption is that the click for the `td` is occurring elsewhere in the `td`, and as such, the handler would be separate. If that's not the case, then OP will probably need to test the `evt.target` in the `td` handler to see if the click was on the `input`, and if so, bypass triggering the `click()` on the `input`.

Comment: Saved my bacon! Awesome answer +1

Answer (score 1):

When you trigger the "click", it's not really a separate event dispatch loop — jQuery is going to run the handlers right there and then. Since your `<input>` is *inside* your `<td>`, the event is going to bubble out to the `<td>` itself, where it'll run smack into that handler again.

Also note that this line here:

```
console.log(input.attr('disabled'), 'disabled');
```

is maybe not what you want - I think that'll always log the word "disabled". Maybe you meant

```
console.log(input.attr('disabled') + ' disabled');
```

Comment: I am using firebug console, so in my case all works as expected.